# Ограничение числа соединений

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Как в asp net core можно ограничить число одновременных запросов, скажем, если число запросов метода превысило какое-то число, отправляем ошибку?

Comment: На конкретный метод возможно удобно будет использовать что-то типа `SemaphoreSlim`, где задавать максимальное число "вхождений" и кидать нужный эксепшн при необходимости. Ну а так, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57464376/11837368

Comment: Можно взять готовый пакет: https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit